# Updating multiple columns in Mysql using C# Textboxes

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to update **4 Columns in  a particular row in MySQL using C#**.I want to update the

value entered in text boxes into the database if a particular field already .I am using the

following query.

```
 string query = " update orderform set enrolmentexpected = " +
    textBox2.Text + " stockonhand=" + textBox3.Text + " numberrequired = "
    + textBox4.Text +  " where name = " + textBox1.Text + ";";
```

I am getting an exception that there is some error in mysql syntax but i am not able to

find such. Is my query right or there is some syntax mistake,and is there some way for

updating multiple columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string query = " update orderform set enrolmentexpected = " +
textBox2.Text + ", stockonhand=" + textBox3.Text + ", numberrequired = "
+ textBox4.Text +  " where name = '" + textBox1.Text + "';"
```

guess that name is a string and other two int

Answer (score 2):

You have numerous problems in that line.

- No comma between values
- No parameters usage [(with Sql Injection Problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection))

Use something like this

```
using(MySqlConnection cn = GetConnection())
{
    cn.Open();
    string queryText = "update orderform set enrolmentexpected = ?en, stockonhand=?st, numberrequired=?num where name = ?name;";     
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryText, cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?en", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?st", textBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?num", textBox4.Text); // ?? require conversion to Int ???
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?name", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot the comma ',' after an expression :

`string query = " update orderform set enrolmentexpected = " +
    textBox2.Text + ", stockonhand=" + textBox3.Text + ", numberrequired = "
    + textBox4.Text +  " where name = " + textBox1.Text + ";";`

and quotes too :

`string query = " update orderform set enrolmentexpected = '" +
    textBox2.Text + "', stockonhand= '" + textBox3.Text + "' , numberrequired = '"
    + textBox4.Text +  "' where name = " + textBox1.Text + ";";`

Comment: @ dada686 When i am entering the previous name to update other columns in row it gives an exception that unknown column name, it takes the value entered into column name as name of the column

Comment: @jaggi This error is because you forgot to put the comma and quotes, so the interpreter is confused as to who is what.

Comment: @jaggi you should look at steve's answer, it is the best way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not using single quotes and commas.
Use this

```
string query = " update orderform set enrolmentexpected = '" +
textBox2.Text + "', stockonhand='" + textBox3.Text + "', numberrequired = '"
+ textBox4.Text +  "' where name = '" + textBox1.Text + "';";
```

This is valid in case all the datatypes are of type char or varchar.